# UWP MediaCapture - Record wav audio with sample rate 16000, 16 bit, mono

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, mediarecorder

I want to include audio recording into my UWP app.
The recording should be saved to a wav file and **must** have the properties sample rate 16000, 16 bit, mono (required for speech recognition tasks). 
Since libraries like CSCore and NAudio do not seem to work for UWP apps, I tried using the MediaCapture API.

Here is my code:

```
MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
  AudioDeviceId = device.Id,
  StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Audio,
};
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("audio.wav", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto), file);
```

I tried to use the following code to set the `AudioEncodingProperties` but it always errors out:

```
var controller = mediaCapture.AudioDeviceController;
var properties = controller.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Audio) as AudioEncodingProperties;
properties.SampleRate = 16000;
properties.BitsPerSample = 16;
properties.ChannelCount = 1;

// the following line fails with System.Exception "The request is invalid in the current state."
await controller.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Audio, properties);
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring MediaEncodingProfile.Audio as follows.

```
var profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
profile.Audio = AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(16000, 1, 16);

await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(profile, file);
```

btw, attempts to alter audio-quality in capturing device side may not succeed, because it doesn't support so many formats.

```
var controller = mediaCapture.AudioDeviceController;
var encoding_properties_supported = controller.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Audio).ToArray();
```